# mongodb remote connection developed with node.js hosting provier doesn't have build in?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, remote-connection

I deployed my little website projected built node,js, and customised, with js, in local development I used database mongodb, in the hosting provider doesn't have the mongodb. They said to connect remotely.

How to connect remotely? I have already a cluster in mongodb atlast web, like connection string:

```
mongoose
    .connect('mongodb+srv://washimulislamData:<password>@mydata.d0jjezh.mongodb.net/signup?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Connected to MongoDB`);
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log(`Node API app is running on port 3000`);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Can you connect from your local development? If you can then you know how to set up ip whitelisting. All you need to do is find out the ip address of your new hosting provider. This might be a single ip address or a CIDR-notated range of addresses. See the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you replace  with your actual database password. i suggest passing it through the .env file.
- In the MongoDB Atlas dashboard, go to the "Network Access" section.
  Add an IP address to allow your hosting provider to access the MongoDB cluster.
- Go to the "Database Access" section in MongoDB Atlas.
  Make sure your MongoDB user has the necessary permissions for the database you are connecting to.